# Uninstall Excel2Latex using Mac Terminal

Tags: excel2latex

I installed Excel2Latex using terminal and want to uninstall it now. Does anyone know the command for this?

Comment: How did you install it? `Excel2Latex` is only one file, isn't it?

Comment: see manpages for `whereis` and `rm`.

Comment: When I open Excel there is a popup window that says '/Applications/MicrosoftExcel.app//Users/MyName/Downloads/excel2latex/Excelt2LaTeX.xla' could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably in your excel add-in directory and you should use the add-in-manager to remove it. But since you asked for a terminal command, here we go:

```
rm `find ~ -name "Excel2LaTeX.xla"`
```

If you somehow managed to install it outside of your home directory (~), try:

```
rm `find / -name "Excel2LaTeX.xla"`
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked in Add-ins under the Insert option up top and couldn't find it, but under Tools there is an "Excel Add-ins" and I found it there. I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Great. That was, what I meant with "add-in-manager"